# How to change one color in html or css or js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

```
.sepia {-webkit-filter: sepia(80%); filter: sepia(80%);}
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:700px;" class="sepia"></div>
```

When writing code as above, It could change the color of the div.

Is there any way to specify the one color can be changed to another one color?

I want to make myself some filter.

Comment: What do you mean with: "Is there any way to specify the one color can be changed to another one color "?

Comment: @SvenB When Image using #0010CC and #DD48FF colors, I want to chnage specific #0010CC to like a #FFFFFF, i don't want change every color.

Comment: use canvas, write some code.

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: @Duncan When I use Google map, Google map api styling doesn't work in when zoom the south korea, that country has locked google map updates. but i need to styling when zoom the south korea.

Comment: @epascarello thanks.. i also think it's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of an image with the hue-rotate() filter

Comment: wrong, hue-rotate has change all image color,i want specific color code, like a #00FF21 ->#BCBCBC

Comment: no.. i mean not every color to some colors, i said specific one color code to change one color code.